# Web Audio - Oscillator AnalyserNode

Tags: web, canvas, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to add [AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) and visualize the output sound to a web audio example that I made but I can't figure out how. I think I am not passing the right source to the analyser (?)

Here for the full code : https://jsfiddle.net/kepin95043/1ub0sjo3/

```
    <script>
        var fs = 2000;
        var gain = 0.2;

        class Sound {
            constructor(context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            init() {
                this.oscillator = this.context.createOscillator();
                this.oscillator.frequency.value = fs;
                this.gainNode = this.context.createGain();
                this.oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);
                this.gainNode.connect(this.context.destination);

            }

            play(value) {
                this.init();
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gain, this.context.currentTime);
                this.oscillator.start();
            }

            stop() {
                this.gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, this.context.currentTime + 1);
                this.oscillator.stop(this.context.currentTime + 1);
            }

        }

        var context = new AudioContext();
        var sound = new Sound(context);
        sound.init();
        var wave = 'sine';
        var state = 'paused';

        var waveSelectors = document.querySelectorAll('.waveform');
        var playBtn = document.querySelector('#play');
        var container = document.querySelector('.container');
        waveSelectors.forEach(function(button) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                cleanClass('active');
                wave = button.dataset.wave;
                sound.oscillator.type = wave;
                button.classList.add('active');
            })
        })

        playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

            context.resume().then(() => {
                console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
            });
            if (playBtn.text == 'Play') {
                sound.play();
                sound.oscillator.type = wave;
                playBtn.text = 'Pause';
            } else {
                sound.stop();
                playBtn.text = 'Play';
            }
        })

        function cleanClass(rclass) {
            waveSelectors.forEach(function(button) {
                button.classList.remove(rclass);
            })
        }

        function changeFs(val) {
            fs = val;
            var output = document.getElementById("fsValue");
            output.innerHTML = val;
            sound.stop();
            sound.play();
            console.log(val);
        };

        function changeGain(val) {
            gain = val;
            var output = document.getElementById("gainValue");
            output.innerHTML = val;
            sound.stop();
            sound.play();
            console.log(val);
        };

    var masterGain;
    masterGain = context.createGain();
    masterGain.connect(context.destination);

    // analyser
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    masterGain.connect(analyser);

    var waveform = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(waveform);

    (function updateWaveform() {
      requestAnimationFrame(updateWaveform);
      analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(waveform);
    }());

    var spectrum = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    (function updateSpectrum() {
      requestAnimationFrame(updateSpectrum);
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrum);
    }());


    // oscilloscope
    var scopeCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    scopeCanvas.width = waveform.length;
    //scopeCanvas.height = 200;
    scopeCanvas.height = scopeCanvas.width * 0.33;
    var scopeContext = scopeCanvas.getContext('2d');

    (function drawOscilloscope() {
      requestAnimationFrame(drawOscilloscope);
      scopeContext.clearRect(0, 0, scopeCanvas.width, scopeCanvas.height);
      scopeContext.strokeStyle="white"; // Green path
      scopeContext.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i < waveform.length; i++) {
        var x = i;
        var y = (0.5 + waveform[i] / 2) * scopeCanvas.height;
        if (i === 0) {
          scopeContext.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
          scopeContext.lineTo(x, y);
        }
      }
      scopeContext.stroke();
    }());

    </script>
```

Could anyone help me to identify what I'm doing wrong?
Thank in advance!

***PS: Open it with Firefox. Does not work on Chromium based browsers for me.***

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/dennisgaebel/pen/YEwLaL

Answer (score 0):

You create a `Sound` object and also a `masterGain` that is connected to your `AnalyserNode`.  But I don't see where the sound ever connects to the `masterGain`.  Without that, your analyser node just gets silence.

Comment: So, should I remove the masteGain object and use the sound one instead to the analyzer? Sorry but I'm newbie and I'm a bit (a lot actually) confused.


I tried with the followings instead but didn't work:
```

var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
1) sound.gainNode.connect(analyser);
2) sound.oscillator.connect(analyser);```

Comment: Start with something simple, without classes and such.  Create an oscillator, connect it to an analyser node and do your animations to draw the waveform.  The WebAudio parts should be quite simple.  Then work your way up from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the full working script code:**

```
var fs = 2000;
var gain = 0.2;

class Sound {
    constructor(context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    init() {
        this.oscillator = this.context.createOscillator();
        this.oscillator.frequency.value = fs;
        this.gainNode = this.context.createGain();
        this.oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);
        this.gainNode.connect(this.context.destination);
    }
    play(value) {
        this.init();
        this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gain, this.context.currentTime);
        this.oscillator.start();
        // connect analyser to the gainedSource
        this.gainNode.connect(analyser);
        // for the non gainedSource
        //this.gainNode.connect(analyser);
    }
    stop() {
        this.gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, this.context.currentTime + 1);
        this.oscillator.stop(this.context.currentTime + 1);
    }
}

var context = new AudioContext();
var sound = new Sound(context);
sound.init();
var wave = 'sine';
var state = 'paused';

var waveSelectors = document.querySelectorAll('.waveform');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('#play');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
waveSelectors.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        cleanClass('active');
        wave = button.dataset.wave;
        sound.oscillator.type = wave;
        button.classList.add('active');
    })
})

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    context.resume().then(() => {
        console.log('Playback resumed successfully');
    });
    if (playBtn.text == 'Play') {
        sound.play();
        sound.oscillator.type = wave;
        playBtn.text = 'Pause';
    } else {
        sound.stop();
        playBtn.text = 'Play';
    }
})

function cleanClass(rclass) {
    waveSelectors.forEach(function(button) {
        button.classList.remove(rclass);
    })
}

function changeFs(val) {
    fs = val;
    var output = document.getElementById("fsValue");
    output.innerHTML = val;
    sound.stop();
    sound.play();
    console.log(val);
};

function changeGain(val) {
    gain = val;
    var output = document.getElementById("gainValue");
    output.innerHTML = val;
    sound.stop();
    sound.play();
    console.log(val);
};


// analyser node
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
var waveform = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(waveform);

(function updateWaveform() {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateWaveform);
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(waveform);
}());

var spectrum = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
(function updateSpectrum() {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateSpectrum);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(spectrum);
}());


// oscilloscope
var scopeCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
scopeCanvas.width = waveform.length;
scopeCanvas.height = scopeCanvas.width * 0.33;
var scopeContext = scopeCanvas.getContext('2d');

(function drawOscilloscope() {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawOscilloscope);
    scopeContext.clearRect(0, 0, scopeCanvas.width, scopeCanvas.height);
    scopeContext.strokeStyle = "white"; // Green path
    scopeContext.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < waveform.length; i++) {
        var x = i;
        var y = (0.5 + waveform[i] / 2) * scopeCanvas.height;
        if (i === 0) {
            scopeContext.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            scopeContext.lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }
    scopeContext.stroke();
}());
```